# Passing Structures between Managed and Unmanaged Code

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I call c++/cli method from c# in this method:

```
        bool SetProperty(Element element, Node referencePoint, List<Materializer> materializers, List<ulong> properties)
    {

        // Loop over STLs
        for (int i = 0; i < materializers.Count; i++)
        {               
            Materializer materializer = materializers[i];
            PentalTreeNode pentalTreeRoot = pentalTreeDatasets[i].top;


            if (materializer.IsPointInside(referencePoint.X, referencePoint.Y, referencePoint.Z, pentalTreeRoot))
            {
                element.PropertyId = properties[i];
                return true;
            };

        }

        return false;
    }
```

C++/cli method is this:

```
bool IsPointInside(double x, double y, double z, PentalTreeNode ^root)
    {
        int intersectionCount = 0;

        Math3d::M3d rayPoints[2], intersectionPoint;

        rayPoints[0].set(x,y,z);
        rayPoints[1].set(x,y,1.0e6);


        if(_box->IsContainingPoint(x,y,z))
        {           
            intersectionCount=CountIntersects(x,y,z,root);
            return (intersectionCount%2!=0);

        }   

    }
```

What is wrong, because c++/cli method doesn't return always the same result?
How to pin or marshal?

Method in c++/cli(Maybe this not ok?):

```
int CountIntersects(double x, double y, double z, PentalTreeNode ^root)
    {

        Math3d::M3d rayPoints[2], intersectionPoint;

        rayPoints[0].set(x,y,z);
        rayPoints[1].set(x,y,1.0e6);

        if(!root) 
            return 0;
        else
        {
            int special = CountIntersects(x,y,z,root->special);
            if (x <= root->xMax && x >= root->xMin && y <= root->yMax && y >= root->yMin)
            {

                if( _stlMesh->IsRayIntersectsPoly(root->index, rayPoints, intersectionPoint))
                {
                    return (1 + special);
                }
                else 
                    return special;
            }
            else
            {
             if (y>root->yMax)
              {
                    return (CountIntersects(x,y,z,root->top)+special);
              }
              else if(y<root->yMin)
                    {
                        return (CountIntersects(x,y,z,root->bottom)+special);
                    }
                    else if(x<root->xMin)
                            {
                                return (CountIntersects(x,y,z,root->left)+special);
                            }
                            else if(x>root->xMax)
                            {
                                return (CountIntersects(x,y,z,root->right)+special);
                            }
                            else 
                                return special;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( _stlMesh->IsRayIntersectsPoly(root->index, rayPoints, intersectionPoint))
```

There's one possible flaw in this particular statement, you've never initialized *intersectionPoint*.  C++ lets you get away with this, it doesn't have anything similar to C#'s definite assignment rules.  It isn't 100% clear whether that's the real problem, the variable might be passed by reference.

In the Debug build, such an uninitialized variable will have a predictable value.  Something you can easily see in the debugger when you switch it to hexadecimal display mode.  Fields in this struct or class will contain the value 0xcccccccc, a value that's apt to generate nonsensical results or crash your code with an access violation.  In the Release build, the /RTC option isn't turned on and you'll get entirely random values in the variable.

Which corresponds very well with the description of your problem, so high odds that this is indeed the problem.  Be sure to use the debugger to find problems like this, you can easily see the value of local variables with the Autos debugger window as you single-step through the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a solution. Than you for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling a C++ method! You are calling a C++/CLI method. And therefore it is normal .NET code and it is always passed correctly. There is no need to pin or marshal anything in C# im this case!

If it returns not the expected values, you should try to find the problem in you C++/CLI project.

Comment: I added once more method from c++/cli... See edited question... Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand you goal or algorythm.... But it is not a problem with passing the values to C++/CLI, so the answer is correct. If you have another question about your algorythm, you should create a new question...

Comment: Ok, it is not a problem with passing the values to c++/cli. Thanks for it. Is problem with passing the values between two c++/cli methods, maybe?

Comment: No... Also this is not the problem here... At least from the code you showed. I assume that your algorythm does not what it should. You can easily test this with unit tests!

Comment: Algorythm is ok... I call c# method in for-loop, and for some iterator values result is wrong... When I set breakpoints for that iterator values, and step over result is ok! When I start program without breakpoints result is wrong for some iterator values...

Comment: Why is the variable intersectionPoint not initialized?

Comment: You have problem in the methos you are calling... Normally this is a result of uninitialized variables.... But this has nothimg to do with the passing of the parameters from maned to CppCLI code!

Comment: I already have one version which also this variable used in the same way... And that version is ok...

Comment: Thanks a lot,solution is in initializing intersectionPoint.